# Blacked out html folder in root directory

Tags: linux, files

Just looking through my system's directories and wondering about some of the contents.

There is a blacked out (inaccessible) directory called `html`. I'm thinkging this is a bad link? I'm guessing and not really sure if I can delete it.

Also there's another directory, `conf.d`, which I've only ever seen in the `/etc/httpd` directory in the past.

Can I safely delete these files/directories? What are their purposes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Unix systems, Linux in particular, it's often a bad idea to just randomly start deleting directories and files that one doesn't know their true purpose.

I would advise you to at a minimum use your distributions package manager to at least determine if the files are owned by some software package.

**RedHat base distros such as Fedora/CentOS/RHEL**

```
$ rpm -qf /var/www/html/
php-pear-1.9.4-20.fc19.noarch
httpd-2.4.6-2.fc19.x86_64
```

The above shows that there are 2 packages that have files that are under this directory.

**Debian/Ubuntu/Mint**

```
$ dpkg -S /etc/cron.d
anacron, cron, sysstat: /etc/cron.d
```

Here we can see that there are 3 packages, `anacron,`cron`, and`sysstat` that all own either that directory or files under it.

#### Purpose of files

Again also check with your system's package management facilities if you're ever in doubt as to the validity and/or purpose of a file. Directories named `conf.d` are used through out Linux systems in a number of ways. The primary purpose is to provide a directory where customization's can go from the user, leaving the original files intact.

This is done as a convenience so that when it comes time to upgrade a software package none of your customization's will be lost.

#### Example

Here's all the `conf.d` directories on my Fedora 19 system.

```
$ sudo find /etc -type d | grep conf.d
/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d
/etc/yum/pluginconf.d
/etc/prelink.conf.d
/etc/httpd/conf.d
/etc/dracut.conf.d
/etc/ld.so.conf.d
/etc/dconf/db
/etc/dconf/db/gdm.d
/etc/dconf/db/gdm.d/locks
/etc/dconf/db/ibus.d
/etc/fonts/conf.d
/etc/reader.conf.d
/etc/polkit-1/localauthority.conf.d
```

Comment: Sorry to take so long to see this answer!